# Weird selector issue

Tags: jquery, html

i have this code :

```
<li>Oui<input name="antecedents" value="1" type="radio" style="margin-right: 10px;" onclick="console.log($('#antecedents').value);"/></li>
<li>Non<input name="antecedents" value="2" type="radio" style="margin-right: 10px;" checked="checked" onclick="console.log($('#antecedents').value);"></li>
```

When i click, i got "undefined" in the console, btw, if i use this.value in the console.log() i have the right result....

If some see something wrong here with the selector... sometimes fresh eyes are better.

Thanks in advance guys.

Comment: Try to use console.log($('[name="antecedents"]').val()

Comment: Please [learn to love labels](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/200711/use_the_label_element_to_make_your_html_forms_accessible/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what you should do:

```
<li>Oui<input name="antecedents" id="antecedents" value="1" type="radio" style="margin-right: 10px;" onclick="console.log($('#antecedents').val());"/></li>
```

`$("#selector")` - this selector matches ids not name attributes. To match a name attribute, use

```
$("input[name=antecedents]").val();
```

Comment: Could the downvoter tell me where I went wrong? Adding an id attribute and matching it properly in jQuery... what's wrong with that?

Comment: That won't work. There are multiple elements with the same name; that code will always return the value of the first one.

Answer (score 4):

## Problem 1

The [id selector](https://api.jquery.com/id-selector/) matches an element based on its [id](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#the-id-attribute).

Your input doesn't have an id, only a [name](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#naming-form-controls:-the-name-attribute).

You can either give the elements ids (remember: an id must be unique in a document) or use an [attribute selector](https://api.jquery.com/multiple-attribute-selector/).

## Problem 2

jQuery objects don't have `value` properties. They have a [`val()` method](http://api.jquery.com/val/).

[`value` is a property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement#Properties) of native DOM objects. You could also get the native DOM object out of the jQuery object and check its value: `$(selector)[0].value`.

## Problem 3

If you use an attribute selector to select multiple elements, then the `val()` method will return the value of the *first* element not the *checked* element.

You need to filter to see which option the user has selected. You can use the [checked selector](https://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/) for this.

---

```
$('[name="antecedents"]:checked').val()
```